WebMIDI - open just 1 MIDI input
Hello Stack overflow and WebMIDI folks,
I have several hardware MIDI devices connected via USB, but I only want to access one of them using WebMIDI on Windows 10. WebMIDI scans all hardware devices before I have a chance to select any device, causing all devices to be marked as 'in use' and preventing Cubase and other MIDI applications from accessing them.
AN example, the Roland UM-2G has 2 MIDI inputs and 2 MIDI outputs. If I access MIDI input (1) with WebMIDI, then MIDI input (2) becomes inaccessible in other applications.
Another example: I have 4 Icon Qcon USB MIDI controllers, a Roland UM-2G, and several other devices. I want to use WebMIDI to access only the Roland USB MIDI input (1), process this input data, and forward it to a virtual MIDI cable (e.g., Loopmidi) into Cubase. Is this possible? And if so, how can I achieve this?
Any help is welcome, cheers,
Rob
No matter what I do in WebMIDI / JavaScript, I can't get it to work!
